# Petición para Banner con lucecitas de neón

Tags: característica-nueva

Desde que iniciaron las clases en Latinoamérica (Marzo-Abril), percibo un aumento en las preguntas del tipo: "*ayuda con mi tarea*". Sería mucho pedir poner un **Banner** enorme (de preferencia con lucecitas de neón) para que **todos los usuarios lean cómo hay que formular preguntas** y siendo un poco más estrictos los nuevos usuarios: una vez que hayan leído las reglas tengan la chance de preguntar, así bien informados se mejorará la calidad de las preguntas.

Este sitio se mantiene con la buena voluntad de todos los que paseamos por aquí, a modo de sugerencia recuerden ese **Banner** para leer las reglas de formulación de preguntas, y el diseño del **Banner** de preferencia con lucecitas de neón para darle ese toque futurista.

Comment: No todos los países de Latinoamérica inician clases en Marzo-Abril :) Referencias: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9rica_Latina, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_escolar

Comment: definitivamente esto se cierra y agrego la idea a "http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado" saludos :D