# ¿Cómo 'obligar' a leer las ayudas?

Tags: característica-nueva, centro-de-ayuda

En el poco tiempo que llevo en la plataforma, he visto que uno de los problemas que existen está relacionado con el uso de la plataforma por parte de usuarios nuevos, que aún no conocen (o conocemos) el manejo y ya sea por vaguería (en este caso no hay nada que hacer) o por desconocimiento, no se hacen preguntas/respuestas de calidad, no se vota, no se aceptan respuestas, etc.

Están muy bien el recorrido y las ayudas que se dan, pero para eso hay que leerlas. Yo las he ido leyendo según me aparecen (son muy cortitas y realmente tengo interés en saber cómo funciona el sitio), pero puedo entender que para algunos esto sea más o menos como los "términos y condiciones", es decir, no me lo leo y bajo hasta el botón de aceptar.

¿No podría hacerse algo para 'asegurar' que sean leídas las páginas de ayuda cuando aparecen? por ejemplo un test sencillisimo al final. Por ejemplo para el recorrido que no active la opción de formular pregunta hasta que todo el test se ha respondido correctamente.

Pongo algún ejemplo de pregunta:

> ¿Para qué sirven las etiquetas?
>
> A. Permiten encontrar preguntas interesantes fácilmente.
>   B. Identifican a cada usuario.
>   C. Aumentan la reputación.
>
> ¿Qué puedes hacer si una respuesta ha solucionado el problema que preguntaste?
>
> A. Agradecerlo al autor en los comentarios.
>   B. Aceptar la respuesta pulsando el tick verde.
>   C. Eliminar el resto de respuestas.

No digo que tengan que ser estas preguntas en concreto, pero son un ejemplo en el que se ve que si has leído la ayuda (estas están basadas en el recorrido) las vas a saber seguro pero si no la has leído es probable que no adivines todas las respuestas del test y por consiguiente no tengas lo derechos que correspondan.

La idea no es "hacer un test y enviarlo", sino simplemente que el usuario marque las casillas del test y hasta que no estén todas marcadas correctamente no desbloquear los privilegios correspondientes.

No sé si es posible, si es buena o mala idea o qué, pero bueno, ya que se me ha ocurrido lo suelto y ya me diréis (si es que he logrado hacer que se entienda la idea).

Comment: Sería bueno, cada vez veo un aumento de preguntas mal redactadas... sin código ni investigación y para variar, urgentes... Aquí un par de publicaciones relacionadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/609/822 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/822

Comment: Comparto con @Rubén mi desacuerdo con la idea. Hace un años había un indicador en el perfil de los usuarios diciendo qué porcentaje de preguntas había marcado como aceptadas. Creaba controversia. A los usuarios de una sola pregunta les daba igual, a los más activos los "marcaba" de alguna forma. Estoy de acuerdo en que es bueno que la gente sepa un mínimo de cómo funciona el sistema, pero creo que para eso el entorno debería ser más intuitivo, especialmente a la hora de preguntar y los pasos posteriores.

Comment: Adrian, esta idea ha rondado desde hace años por Meta y seguirá haciéndolo. No se cual es la solución absoluta, pero si te puedo decir dos cosas. En vez de tratar de controlar la creación, hay que controlar la moderación. La recomendación debe ser votar mas y atender mas las colas de revisiones. Eso ayudara mas al sitio que otras cosas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Obligar* a leer antes de publicar una pregunta/respuesta es "mala idea" porque una de las premisas de la plataforma es que cualquiera pueda publicar **una** pregunta o respuesta sin obstáculo alguno. Según he observado toda [característica-nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva) que ha ido en una dirección contraria ha sido "olímpicamente ignorada" por la Compañía (quizás han respondido, dado muestras de aprecio por las ideas, el interés y dado explicaciones, pero nada ha trascendido en lo que a modificar la plataforma se refiere).

Por el contrario no cualquiera puede votar ni comentar en cualquier pregunta, tampoco puede participar en meta ni el chat.

Cabe destacar que

1. existen límites a la cantidad de preguntas y respuestas que se pueden hacer los cuales varían con base en la puntuación que tengan las preguntas y respuestas respectivamente.

   - He aquí una muy buena razón para votar
2. una de las iniciativas actuales de la Compañía (véase la ref. 1) es ayudar a los nuevos usuarios a hacer buenas preguntas.
3. existen filtros (quizás sólo en inglés) que bloquean la publicación de spam y preguntas muy pero muy malas.

Sin embargo, algo que podría hacerse es no responder las preguntas, por ejemplo, que no sigan las guías de uso de la etiqueta más popular que corresponda a la pregunta, así como votar, dejar comentarios para orientar al AP sobre cómo mejorar la pregunta incluyendo la sugerencia de leer la documentación que has mencionado.

En síntesis, sugiero que votemos y/o dejemos comentarios cada vez que leamos una pregunta o respuesta.

NOTA: Se ha sugerido aquí en Meta evitar votar negativo en las publicaciones que ya tienen una puntuación negativa porque algunos autores a los que les ha pasado han compartido que la experiencia fue muy desagradable.

Referencias

1. [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/1595451)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, aunque no considero que ese sencillo test (que igual no ha quedado muy claro, la idea no es que fuese para poder preguntar, sino para cada vez que se debloqueen privilegios y recibas 'intrucciones') sea obstaculizar. Entiendo que si lo sería si tuviese la más mínima complicación, pero por eso he puesto que habría de ser un test sencillisimo que demuestre que has leído el texto. Aún así, otra vez, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.